# How to stop an activity from starting while checking if a user is logged in?

Tags: android, accountmanager

I am trying to achieve the following when a user starts my app:

1- if the user is not logged in then show a login screen.
2- If the user as already created an account and there is a valid token then show start screen.

To this end I have implemented a custom Authenticator based on the tutorial found here http://www.udinic.com/.

The code works, my issue is that it shows the current activity UI briefly then switches to the add Account UI provided by my AccountAuthenticator. How can I fixed this?

This is the code:

```
   @Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    getTokenForAccountCreateIfNeeded(AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE,    AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS);


}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mAccountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
}


  /**
 * Get an auth token for the account.
 * If not exist - add it and then return its auth token.
 * If one exist - return its auth token.
 * If more than one exists - show a picker and return the select account's auth token.
 * @param accountType
 * @param authTokenType
 */
private void getTokenForAccountCreateIfNeeded(String accountType, String authTokenType) {
    final AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future = mAccountManager.getAuthTokenByFeatures(accountType, authTokenType, null, this, null, null,
            new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
                @Override
                public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
                    Bundle bnd = null;
                    try {
                        bnd = future.getResult();
                        final String authtoken = bnd.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                        showMessage(((authtoken != null) ? "SUCCESS!\ntoken: " + authtoken : "FAIL"));


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        showMessage(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
    , null);
}
```

force my users to login at the start of the app. I have implemented a custom Authenticator based on the tutorial found here http://www.udinic.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Since your authentication method is asynchronous, you can't prevent the UI from showing. I would implement a Router/Splashscreen `Activity` that checks the authentication status and then starts either the Login `Activity` or actual `Activity` the user sees if he's logged in. Make sure you set your Router `Activity` to `nohistory` in your manifest.

If you want to keep it in a single `Activity`, you should have a full-screen loading indicator in your layout that lays on top of the UI and fades out once you have figured out which layout to show.